# What's the proper way to use logger along with context?

Tags: logging, go

I am building a web server in Golang. You know Golang has an `context` package and it's [offically recommended](https://blog.golang.org/context) to always pass a context as first argument. `context.Context` has a `Value` method to keep variables under a context.

However, most logging libraries also privide a way to inherit logger, say, creating child loggers with fields from its parent. In [logrus](https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus) (or some other logger, doesn't matter), you may create an `logrus.Entry` and apply `WithFields` to get a child logger.

For example, when each HTTP request coming an `request-id` is attached. I hope it being put in context, and also logged as a field in every log.

So, how to do this in a proper way?

THANKS!!

Comment: Have you tried to actually do it or are you just asking for us to do it for you?

Comment: While a `Context` may provide execution context it does much more, especially handle cancellation. Why do you think `Context` would be the most appropriate way to handle derived loggers? (It is not.)

Comment: I do pretty much exactly what you are talking about. I have a middleware that sets up a `logrus.Entry` with session and request info (url, request-id, etc...) . Then I have a log pkg of my own with a function that takes a context and returns a `logrus.Entry`, if it finds a `logrus.Entry` on the context it uses it if not it creates a new one.

Comment: @Volker It really depends. For example, in my project we use logrus, and for indexing log in ElasticSearch we want to set logrus.Fields like `user_id` outside of the default "msg" field. So a cleaner way is create an Entry by `logrus.WithField` in a middleware when we capture `user_id` and reuse the Entry throughout a lifecycle of the request by passing the entry in a context.

In this manner, this logger becomes actually a request specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can set and get requestID in context using http middleware

```
package requestid

type requestIDKey struct{}

func ContextWithRequestID(ctx context.Context, requestID string) context.Context {
    return context.WithValue(ctx, requestIDKey{}, requestID)
}

func FromContext(ctx context.Context) string {
    val := ctx.Value(requestIDKey{})
    if val == nil {
       return ""
    }
    return val.(string)
}

func HTTPMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        requestID := r.Header.Get("X-Request-ID")
        if requestID == "" {
            requestID = uuid.New().String()
        }
        ctx := ContextWithRequestID(r.Context(), requestID)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}
```

And then create a global logger with exported wrapper functions that receive context as an argument (in this example i am using [zap](https://github.com/uber-go/zap), but it can be any other logger)

```
package logger

var globalLogger *zap.SugaredLogger

func init() {
    globalLogger = zap.NewExample().Sugar()
}

func loggerWithRequestID(ctx context.Context) *zap.SugaredLogger {
    return globalLogger.With("request_id", requestid.FromContext(ctx))
}

func Errorf(ctx context.Context, template string, args ...interface{}) {
    loggerWithRequestID(ctx).Errorf(template, args...)
}
//Warn,Warnf...
```

So it can be used anywhere in code like this:

```
logger.Error(ctx, "encountered error")
```

Comment: This is 100% a beautiful example, except that I would not use a global variable here and simply init the logger in `main`, since I tend to avoid `init` but YMMV

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `request-id` from the incoming request and then use the context to pass the `request-id` to the functions you are calling. 
Here is an example of that : https://medium.com/@cep21/how-to-correctly-use-context-context-in-go-1-7-8f2c0fafdf39. 
For logging: Define your own logger using the std log library

```
func CreateCustomLogger(requestId string) *log.Logger {
    defaultLoggingFlags := 
log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.LUTC|log.Lmicroseconds|log.Lshortfile
    return log.New(os.Stderr, requestId + ": ", defaultLoggingFlags)
}
```

In your function:

```
customLogger := CreateCustomLogger(requestId)
customLogger.Printf("Custom log message")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom formatter and set it. Have a look [here](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus#formatters).

Answer (score 0):

Each Http request has it's own context, i just merge request id in it like this in middleware.

```
Request = Request.WithContext(context.WithValue(Request.Context(), "request_uuid", uid))
```